# In react, setting up on('change') handler for stripe cardElement, issue with null values

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

We are attempting to use the cardElement.on('change') functionality in our react application. We have the following:

```
function OurApp = () => {

    const stripe = useStripe();
    let cardElement = elements.getElement('card');
    // let cardElement = elements ? elements.getElement('card') : null;
    cardElement.on('change', (event) => {
        // do something on change
    });

    return (
        <CardElement
            options={cardElementOpts}
        />
    )
}
```

When we run the code above, we receive the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElement')` because `stripe === null` on the first rendering. If we replace the `let cardElement =`  line with `elements ? elements.getElement('card') : null;`, we receive the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on')` because `cardElement === null` and null has no `.on`.

How can we properly setup the on('change') here?

**update**: useEffect that doesn't seem close to working. I need to check for non null for both `elements` and `carddElement`

```
let cardCheck = elements ? elements.getElement('card') : null;
useEffect(() => {
    if (elements) {
        let carddElement = elements.getElement('card');
        if (carddElement) {
            cardCheck.on('change', (event) => {
                console.log('event: ', event);
            });
        }
    }
}, [elements, cardCheck]);
```

Comment: Those are side effects. You should consider using `useEffect` hook to handle side effects

Comment: It seems like there should be a better way to handle this rather than `useEffect`, I try to avoid `useEffect`s whenever possible

Comment: That `on` event should go into a useEffect. Otherwise you are creating bunch of event listeners every time React rendering your component. You should use useEffect's cleanup function to clean up old even listners

Comment: Same for the `elements.getElement('card');`. You can keep this on a `ref` so it won't get call every time component get re rendered

Comment: makes sense, although I am struggling with the useEffect() as well. First render when the useEffect runs, I am receiving the same issue w/ `null` values

Comment: Do you use the React [wrapper](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#element-components) from stripe ?

Comment: yes using the react stripe library for this

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't providing your function to the Element's `onChange` prop? https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#element-components:~:text=Element%20loses%20focus.-,onChange,-optional%20(event%3A%20Object

Comment: Here is a demo of CardElement providing a function to react to changes through the prop https://jsfiddle.net/crx0pv6e/3/

Comment: @Pompey yes, because I am an inexperienced react dev, and was simply mimicking what I saw in the SO post I had linked to. This is exactly what I needed, to use the <CardElement> onChange, thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that that helped!  I'm learning React now too so I get the struggle. Good luck writing the rest of your app. I'll write this up as an answer in case anyone else runs across this post.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's Elements have an `onChange` property[1] that allows you to pass in the function to handle any changes to the element. When your handler is called, an event object will be passed in that includes non-sensitive information on what has changed within the element (the stripe.js reference doc lays out what info you will get in this event[2]).

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log('[change]:', event);
};

function OurApp = () => {

    const stripe = useStripe();
    let cardElement = elements.getElement('card');
    // let cardElement = elements ? elements.getElement('card') : null;
    cardElement.on('change', (event) => {
        // do something on change
    });

    return (
        <CardElement
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
    )
}
```

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#element-components:~:text=Element%20loses%20focus.-,onChange,-optional%20(event%3A%20Object

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=cardElement#element_on_change-handler